# As used in combination CollapsingToolbarLayout, Toolbar and Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, toolbar, navigation-drawer

I have a project that contains only one activity with navigation drawer. Other pages is fragments. Other pages are fragments that are placed in FrameLayout the the markup of this activity. Accordingly, one toolbar for all the pages and added to the layout in the activity.
Activity has the following layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_mainactivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_mainactivity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.toolbartheme"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.toolbarstyle"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_content_mainactivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            style="@style/AppTheme.framestyle">
        </FrameLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/menudrawer_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            style="@style/AppTheme.navigationdrawer"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The fragments I want to do сollapsing toolbar. How can i do this? However, this property can only be done in the layout which includes a toolbar. But I have a layouts fragments without toolbar. I would really appreciate any ideas. Thank you for advance!